# Creating a ML algorithm where the train data does not have same number of columns in all records

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

So I have the following train data (no header, explanation bellow):

```
[1.3264,1.3264,1.3263,1.32632]
[2.32598,2.3256,2.3257,2.326,2.3256,2.3257,2.32566]
[10.3215,10.3215,10.3214,10.3214,10.3214,10.32124]
```

It does not have an header because all elements with exception of the last 1 on each array are inputs and the last one is the result/output.

So taking first example: 1.3264,1.3264,1.3263 are inputs/feed data that I want to give to the algorith and 1.32632 is the outcome/result.

All of these are historical values that would lead to a pattern recognition.
I would like to give some test data to the algorith and he would give me outcome/result based on that pattern he identified.

From all the examples I looked into with ML and sklearn, I have never seen one where you have(for the same type of data) multiple entries. They all seem to have the same number of columns and diferent types of inputs whereas mine is always the same type of input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try two different approaches:

1. Extract features from your variable length data to make the features have fixed size. After that you can use any algorithm from `sklearn` or other packages. Feature extraction is highly domain-specific process that requires context of what the data actually is. For example you can try similar features:

```py
import numpy as np


def extract_features_one_row(arr):
    arr = np.array(arr[:-1])
    y = arr[-1]

    features = [
        np.mean(arr),
        np.sum(arr),
        np.median(arr),
        np.std(arr),
        np.percentile(arr, 5),
        np.percentile(arr, 95),
        np.percentile(arr, 25),
        np.percentile(arr, 75),
        (arr[1:] > arr[:-1]).sum(),  # number of increasing pairs
        (arr > arr.mean()).sum(),  # number of elements > mean value
        # extract trends, number of modes, etc
    ]
    return features, y


data = [
    [1.3264, 1.3264, 1.3263, 1.32632],
    [2.32598, 2.3256, 2.3257, 2.326, 2.3256, 2.3257, 2.32566],
    [10.3215, 10.3215, 10.3214, 10.3214, 10.3214, 10.32124],
]

X, y = zip(*[extract_features_one_row(row) for row in data])
X = np.array(X)  # (3, 10)
print(X.shape, y)
```

So now `X_data` have the same number of columns.

2. Use ML algorithm that supports variable length data: Recurrent neural networks, transformers, convolutional networks with padding.

Comment: Understood the 1st part but I don't think is going to work.
The last digit of the array is the result.
You can look at it as almost the mean:


Input: 1.3264   1.3264    1.3263
Result: 1.32632

What I am looking for is a pattern/way/function to endup with the result based on the input.

In this same example the mean would not be enough, there would need to be like a factor (in this case less than 1) to reach the value

Comment: I've updated an example to include (x, y) pairs generation. So you need to add more features that takes into account differences: minimal abs difference between elements, maximal abs differences, etc.